# How do I use multiple modes in codemirror?

Tags: javascript, php, html, codemirror, codemirror-modes

I wrote a code for editor which supports HTML, CSS, JavaScript,  PHP.
I want to add C, C++, Java modes also. So what should I do for that ? And also want to highlight the syntax.

Comment: You will need to use code highlight library and have different mirrors created by codemirrors.

Comment: Ok so it's not possible to use multiple modes like mode = "XML","htmlmixed";